# Setting min/max values for Singleband Pseudocolor using PyQGIS have no effect

Tags: pyqgis

How do I set the min/max values of my Singleband pseudocolor layer style using PyQGIS?

The new values are set, but the layer style does not change.

If I set them manually the update is instant. But if I set max to 0.1 using pyqgis the value change but the layer looks the same. I have to erase and type 0.1 for it to update.

```
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("NDVItest2")[0]
newrend = layer.renderer().clone()
newrend.setClassificationMin(0)
newrend.setClassificationMax(0.1)
layer.setRenderer(newrend)
iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
iface.mapCanvas().refreshAllLayers()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, after a bit of trying it out: You are likely missing the equivalent of hitting the "Classify" button in the GUI, as well as triggerRepaint.

```py
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("NDVItest2")[0]
newrend = layer.renderer().clone()
newrend.setClassificationMin(0)
newrend.setClassificationMax(0.1)
layer.setRenderer(newrend)
newrend.shader().rasterShaderFunction().classifyColorRamp()
layer.triggerRepaint()
```